# Query with multiple COUNTS() and a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a query that returns all the ship parts, factory parts, the date each was entered, and by whom with their respective email. But I need the totall count of all the ship parts and factory parts each person has entered so I added the COUNT functions you see below but I keep gettng this error "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference." Any ideas?

```
select Distinct cc.FirstName+' '+cc.LastName AS 'Name', UEmail AS 'Email', sp.SEntered AS 'Date Entered', COUNT(sp.SHIPID) AS 'Shipments',   COUNT(pn.PNumber) AS 'Factory Parts'
from R_USERS_Detail U
join R_SHIPMENTS sp on sp.UID=U.UID
join R_SHIPMENTOrders sd on sd.SHIPID=sp.SHIPID
join R_PARTOrders pn on pn.PNumberID=sd.PNumberID
join R_Clients c on c.COClientID=sp.COClientID AND c.COClientAcronym LIKE '%AME%'
join R_Contacts cc on cc.COContactID=u.COContactID
group by u.UEmail, sp.SEntered, 'Name'
```

Comment: 1) SQL Server or MySQL? 2) DISTINCT and GROUP BY in one query? 3) `select cc.FirstName+' '+cc.LastName AS 'Name', UEmail AS 'Email', sp.SEntered AS 'Date Entered', COUNT(sp.SHIPID) AS 'Shipments',   COUNT(pn.PNumber) AS 'Factory Parts'
from R_USERS_Detail U
join R_SHIPMENTS sp on sp.UID=U.UID
join R_SHIPMENTOrders sd on sd.SHIPID=sp.SHIPID
join R_PARTOrders pn on pn.PNumberID=sd.PNumberID
join R_Clients c on c.COClientID=sp.COClientID AND c.COClientAcronym LIKE '%AME%'
join R_Contacts cc on cc.COContactID=u.COContactID
group by u.UEmail, sp.SEntered, cc.FirstName+' '+cc.LastName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the exact expression in the `group by` claus , not the alias.

```
select cc.FirstName+' '+cc.LastName AS 'Name'
     , UEmail AS 'Email'
     , sp.SEntered AS 'Date Entered'
     , COUNT(sp.SHIPID) AS 'Shipments'
     , COUNT(pn.PNumber) AS 'Factory Parts'
from R_USERS_Detail U
join R_SHIPMENTS sp on sp.UID=U.UID
join R_SHIPMENTOrders sd on sd.SHIPID=sp.SHIPID
join R_PARTOrders pn on pn.PNumberID=sd.PNumberID
join R_Clients c on c.COClientID=sp.COClientID AND c.COClientAcronym LIKE '%AME%'
join R_Contacts cc on cc.COContactID=u.COContactID
group by u.UEmail, sp.SEntered, cc.FirstName+' '+cc.LastName
```

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much, one last question if you dont mind is there any way for the name to appear once? i ran it and the shipments and parts have been totaled but each person is appearing multiple times, I am thinking its because the date entered is different is there any way to fix that?

Comment: well if the date entered is different and you are grouping it by date then you will see multiple instances of the same person with different dates, you can manipulate the query a little but more to show a specific date something like last date or the first date etc.